# UPDATE SQL statement using regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I have 2 tables, one named pictures and another named media,  in table `pictures` I have the field `description` which contains some text,  In table `media` there is the row `url` that I would like to update.  I need to write an sql query that updates row `url` in table media that uses regex for an specific string in `description` from table `pictures`, can this be done with one sql query?

Comment: Seeing your table structure and the relationships would help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use REGEXP to search for strings but you cannot return the result. If that's alright then you could try something like this:

If your table is something like:

```
create table media(media_id int, url varchar(200));
create table pictures(pic_id int, media_id int, description text);
```

You could do something like this:

```
UPDATE pictures p
LEFT JOIN media m 
ON p.media_id = m.media_id
SET url='http://newurl.com/pic.jpg'
WHERE REGEXP '.*regexpString$';
```

If you need to just replace part of the URL you could try:

```
UPDATE pictures p
LEFT JOIN media m 
ON p.media_id = m.media_id
SET url=REPLACE(url, 'olddomain.com', 'newdomain.com')
WHERE REGEXP '.*regexpString$';
```

Comment: @llion hi thanks for the response!, I need to return the response because in the field description contains part of the path that I need for updating url,

Comment: in the first code-part you wrote picture (singular) and then you wrote pictures (plural). was this on purpose?

Comment: Nope, that was a typo. Fixing it now.